# How to use OR condition in mule dataweave for reading data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mule, conditional-statements, dataweave

Mule 3.8.5 + Data-weave code query :-

I am trying to fetch records from mongodb which is equal to the code passed in input query param OR if the code is equal to static String "ALL".

the above is not working, can anyone suggest the correct syntax to write in transform message component?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
 {
    "code" : [ upper inboundProperties."http.query.params".code or "ALL"]
 }
```

Example if i pass code as "IND" it should return me records having code equal to "IND" or "ALL".
result = IND, ALL, ALL.

Comment: updated the answer based on the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `default`:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
 {
    "code" : [ upper inboundProperties."http.query.params".code default "ALL"]
 }
```

**UPDATE.**

Based on the mongo query syntax here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

```
db.inventory.find( { status: { $in: [ "A", "D" ] } } )
```

Although you can express this query using the $or operator, use the $in operator rather than the $or operator when performing equality checks on the same field.

This should generate the json query in the correct format:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var code = inboundProperties."http.query.params".code
---
{
    "code" : { "\$in": [ upper code, "ALL" ] when code !=null otherwise  ["ALL"] }
}
```

You might need to convert it to a string first before being used by the mongo query.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your response, unfortunately It didn't work for me...The result is null though i was expecting about 27 records. I am trying to fetch column B values from mongodb table if column A has value equal to the one passed in input param OR the value is "ALL". ( In SQL world it would be select <column B value> from table XYZ where <columnA> = <code passed in input param> OR "ALL". For example In the mongoDB table if there are 5 records with column A=ALL and 1 records which is equal to input param code. Then the result would have 6 records.

Comment: Hope i am able to explian. I am running finddocuments operation against mongodb.